# How to prevent my user from being able to do something for a certain amount of time

Tags: java, android, firebase

So I have 3 games that my user is allowed to play. When they finish playing these games, just the once, I want to be able to lock them out of the game a period of time (let's say 30 seconds for now). I know you can use handler's and stuff, but I don't think it meets my requirements. When the user finishes the game, they are pushed back to the menu and a timer shows on top of the button to show how long they need to wait, the button is disabled but the others aren't (for the other games), works fine okay. If they exit out of the app or leave it, how do I make this timer continue and not reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to transfer data across app instances, you should persist the data in disk.

In this case You can store the time of game ending in shared preference and in Activity onCreate check if the minimum time (30 sec ) has passed since the stored time,

Comment: Perfect, I didn't even think of this! Thank you bud